# In an ordinary Blazor web page, is there any way to run a web view on the page?

Tags: iframe, browser, blazor-webassembly, cross-site

In an ordinary Blazor WebAssembly web page, is there any way to run a web view on the page?  That is, to effectively have a
"inner" browser on my page within my actual Browser, whether it's WebView2 or something else?

If there is no Blazor-specific way to do this, is there a non-Blazor (Javascript or otherwise) way?

I realize this is a strange thing to do, but I'd like to experiment with showing pages from other sites where an iframe won't work due to the `frame-ancestors 'self'` policy.  I'm sure this is generally discouraged and a bad practice, but like I said, these are just experiments and for learning.

Note I'm not asking about a mobile, WPF, MAUI, or any other native app, just the use case of having a browser on an actual web page.

Comment: Have a look at `RenderFragment` and `MarkupString`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to experiment with showing pages from other sites where an iframe won't work due to the frame-ancestors 'self' policy

Unfortunately, no there is not a way to do what you are asking as you have a requirement that it must work in a normal browser with websites that prevent exactly what you are asking for. It would be a failure in browser security if it was possible.